# Create a config file for MacOs application

Tags: swift, macos, plist

I am  creating an application on MacOS using swift. I want the end-user to save some details in a config file like "Server Address" ,"port" etc. My app reads from this config file and used the values at runtime. What kind of files are used on MacOs as config files? What extensions would they have? I came across plist files. But I am confused if this file can be used by a end-user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real Mac apps don't use user editable config files, but store their settings in `UserDefaults`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults